# ACL Resources Access Customization and Admin form customization

Tags: magento2, admin, catalog, user-roles, acl

I am new to magento so can somebody please help me out?

I have created a new user (belonging to custom role group = `vendor`) who can login to admin panel and add their own products, for that i have used the new product form specified in catalog module (url : `...admin/catalog/product/new/set...`). Now there are 2 things that I want to do:

1.) On that form their are some fields (like `Attribute Set`) that should be visible only if user role belongs to group `Administrators` and not the custom role group (`vendor`) that I created. How can I modify those form fields to be hidden and have a default value on `vendor` login?

2.) The custom role users should only be able to access the product add/edit form and not the product listing page (I have created custom listing that shows products added by that user which needs to be displayed instead of the entire catalog product listing). How can I achieve this? If I give access to `Magento_Catalog::products` resource, they can access the product listing page also which I need to deny access to.